# Lose Textbox Focus

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox, focus

In my Windows Phone 7 Application I've written a bit of code to make the focus jump to the next textbox on the return key bein pressed. This all works fine, but now what I want to do is get the software keyboard out of the way if the user pressed return on the final textbox. However there is no UnFocus() method. What should I do instead? :)

I thought about Focusing something else (e.g. The PhoneApplicationPage) but this doesnt have a Focus() method.

```
        public List<TextBox> Textboxes = new List<TextBox> { };

    public void CheckForReturn(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox ThisTextbox = sender as TextBox;
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            int ThisTextboxListPosition = Textboxes.IndexOf(ThisTextbox);
            int NextTextboxListPosition = ThisTextboxListPosition + 1;

            if (NextTextboxListPosition < Textboxes.Count)
            {
                TextBox NextTextBox = Textboxes[NextTextboxListPosition];
                NextTextBox.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                //Something like this!
                //ThisTextbox.Unfocus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there no other UIElements on the page you could shift focus to? For example, if you have a TextBlock explaining what the Textbox is for, you could use `myTextBlock.Focus()`. Alternatively, when the user presses Enter on the last Textbox, you can try setting the last Textbox to be `readonly` (then switch back).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am always use in this situation

```
this.Focus()
```